# Insert dynamic data to mysql with python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDITED >>>>>

I write some code which return two outputs but an error appears.

What is the main problem of my code?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os
import sys
import codecs
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pymysql
import mysql.connector

for i in range(1): #electronic

    my_url = "https://www.xxxxx.com/mobile_phones/?facet_is_mpg_child=0&viewType=gridView&page="

    uClient = uReq(my_url + str(i))

    page_html = uClient.read()

    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div" , {"class" : "sku -gallery" })

    for container in containers:

        name = container.img["alt"]

        title_container = container.findAll("span", {"class" : "brand"})

        Brand = title_container[0].text

        price = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price"} )

        price_one = price[0].text.strip()

        price_old = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price -old "})
        price_two = '0'
        if len(price_old) > 0:
            price_two = price_old[0].text.strip()

        rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
        ranking = 'N/A'
        if len(rank) > 0:
            ranking = rank[0].text.strip()

conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="prod")
x = conn.cursor()
#name1 = name()
#brand1 = Brand()
#price_one1 = price_one1()
#price_two1= price_one1()
#rank1 = rank()

x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

> C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
>   C:/Users/xxxx/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/bd.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/xxxx/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/bd.py", line 54, in
>   
>       x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))
>   File
>   "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 170, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 328, in _query
>       conn.query(q)   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 516, in query
>       self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)   File
>   "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 727, in _read_query_result
>       result.read()   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 1066, in read
>       first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 683, in _read_packet
>       packet.check_error()   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py",
>   line 220, in check_error
>       err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)   File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py",
>   line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
>       raise errorclass(errno, errval) pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.'2')' at line 1")
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the variable `rank`. You are supposed to pass `ranking` but you missed it somehow. 
by the code you have given,

```
rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"}) # resultset
if len(rank) > 0:
    ranking = rank[0].text.strip() #result
```

So the change is

```
x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))
```

and you are ready to go! I have some suggestions for you. if you are using `if` condition always give an else condition or a default value for the variable getting declared within the conditional statement. Or else you might end up in error when the condition fails. Like,

```
rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
ranking = rank[0].text.strip() if len(rank) > 0 else 'N/A'
```

Or,

```
rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
ranking = 'N/A'
if len(rank) > 0:
    ranking = rank[0].text.strip()
```

Cheers!

Comment: I changed and again ERORR
`File "C:/Users/xxxx/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/bd.py", line 53, in <module>
    x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)`

Comment: Can you post the actual query which is getting generated? Use print() instead of x.execute()

Comment: I changed to    `rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
ranking = 'N/A'
if len(rank) > 0:
    ranking = rank[0].text.strip()`
     and again ERORR   **first post UPDATE**

Comment: The error seems to be in the query as you can find `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.'2')' at line 1")` in your error message. I can help you only if you provide the actual query which is getting generated.

Comment: `print("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))`    result ==>>  **INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s.%s) ('Galaxy A8 (2018) 64GB Gold', 'Samsung\xa0', '53,300,000ریال', '0', '2')

Process finished with exit code 0**

Comment: You have given a full stop before last %s ((%s,%s,%s,%s`.`%s)). That is what giving error. Change it to comma.

Comment: `x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES **(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)**" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))`

Comment: `x.execute("INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" , (name,Brand,price_one,price_two,ranking))` it is OK but When I'm printing ==> **INSERT INTO list (productname,brand,price1,price2,rank) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ('گوشی 6303', '\xa0', '2,800,000ریال', '0', '1')**  when run x.execute  inset to mysql ===> **But in the price table, only 28 is stored. I think because of its last letters and the dashes between numbers. Because when I change the type of Columns price1 & price2  from INT to TEXT, it is fully displayed**

Comment: Yes, sure! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code stores the information on the csv file, but now I need to save it to mysql.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os
import sys
import unicodecsv as csv
import codecs
from urllib.request import urlopen


for i in range(3): #electronic

    my_url = "https://www.xxxx.com/mobile_phones/?facet_is_mpg_child=0&viewType=gridView&page="

    uClient = uReq(my_url + str(i))

    page_html = uClient.read()

    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div" , {"class" : "sku -gallery" })

    filename = "mobile.csv"
    f = codecs.open(filename, "a" , "utf-8-sig")
    headers = "name, Brand, price_one, price_two, ranking\n"
    f.write(headers)


    for container in containers:

        name = container.img["alt"]

        title_container = container.findAll("span", {"class" : "brand"})

        Brand = title_container[0].text

        price = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price"} )

        price_one = price[0].text.strip()

        price_old = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "price -old "})
        price_two = 0
        if len(price_old) > 0:
            price_two = price_old[0].text.strip()

        rank = container.findAll("span",{"class" : "rating-aggregate"})
        if len(rank) > 0:
            ranking = rank[0].text.strip()

        print("name " + name)
        print("Brand "+ Brand)
        print("price_one " + price_one)
        print("price_two {}".format(price_two))  #----> 
        print("ranking " + ranking)

        f.write(name + "," + Brand.replace(",", "|") + "," + price_one.replace(",", "") + "," + price_two.replace(",", "") + "," + ranking + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: The problem is with the query which is getting formed from your query. try to get the query formed.